# Correctly Implementing a Linked List in C

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

I am trying to implement a linked list from scratch in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node * next;
};

void insert(struct node** root, int data){ 

    // Create a Node

    struct node * temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = NULL;

    // Either root is NULL or not

    if (*root == NULL){
        *root = temp; // Directly modify the root
    }

    else {
        struct node * t = *root;
        while (t->next!=NULL){
            t = t->next;
        }
        t->next = temp; // Append at the last
    }
}

void printList(struct node * root){

    while(root!=NULL){
        printf("%d\t", root->data);
    }

}

struct node * search(struct node* root, int key){

    while (root!=NULL) {
        if (root->data == key) return root;
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main(){

    struct node * head = NULL;

    insert(&head,0);
    insert(&head,1);
    insert(&head,2);
    insert(&head,3);
    insert(&head,4);

    printList(head);

}
```

Now, when I run the program, my output is:

```
0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
```

However, my list doesn't contain all zeroes or 10 elements.

My logic seems correct but somehow code has a bug.

On a side note, is there a way to avoid double pointers, can't I work with only pointers while inserting in a linked list?

Comment: How is [c++] language relevant to this question?

Comment: @user2079303 linked list is implemented similarly in c plus plus

Comment: `while(root!=NULL){` root is never changed inside this print-loop. BTW: this is a good reason to prefer for() loops over while() loops.

Comment: `My logic is correct but somehow code has a bug.` That's not how it works. At a first glance, your printList function doesn't walk the list, but only prints root->data.

Comment: With some very basic debugging you could have found bug that yourself.

Comment: @DeiDei yes...somehow i was too sure that I won't make a mistake in printList function.. inspected insert function only

Comment: @MichaelWalz any pointers on avoiding double pointers?

Comment: @mourinho in C the only way to avoid a double pointer is if `insert` returns the head pointer, e.h: `struct node *insert(struct node* root, int data) ...  `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a small bug in the `printList()` function.

In `printList()` function, `root` not updated, to iterate whole list you should do `root = root->next`

```
void printList(struct node * root){

        while(root!=NULL){
                printf("%d\t", root->data);
                root = root->next; /* you miss this one */
        }

}
```

Same mistake is repeated in `search()` function also,

```
struct node * search(struct node* root, int key){
        while (root!=NULL) {
                if (root->data == key)
                        return root;
                else
                        root = root->next; /* if key not found root should be updated to next one */
        }
        return NULL;
}
```